# What is the maximum magnetic flux density a HDD can tolerate before data is corrupted?

Tags: electromagnetism, hard-drive, hdd

Does anyone have hard numbers explaining the maximum number of Teslas a hard disk drive can tolerate before data will be corrupted.

[This forum](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/FreeAgent-Products/Magnet-sources-and-drive-safety/m-p/100002) says "a lot", which isn't super helpful.

[This one](http://www.techhive.com/article/116572/article.html) claims you need magnets that only governments have access to in order to erase data, but I'm concerned with what it takes to *corrupt* data, not completely erase it.

Comment: There is a big difference between corrupting a spinning disk and corrupting a static disc. When exposed to even a fairly modest magnetic field, eddy currents will be able to magnify the magnetic field in a spinning disc locally easily by an order of magnitude, maybe two. This may even be worsened by the proximity effect. Whereas a static disc will need ridiculous field strengths like Myforwik's answer.

Comment: @user36129 some smaller drives use glass platters so I guess that would make a large difference.

Answer (score 2):

The field intensity required is about 240,000 A/m to penetrate a typical metal harddisk.

Most industry 'wipers' that deguass drives work at between 280,000 to 800,000 A/m.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Where did you get this number from? :)